# Delegating additional stake to solana in the existing public key

Tags: solana, solana-cli

Hello I have a stake account for Solana here is the link

https://explorer.solana.com/address/4EZRbSFYUQeuNCtY3Tv5tqprpTk9Ak7CZPzPsXKm1qLD/tokens?cluster=testnet

This is how I have created a stake account and funded some `SO`L to it

Create stake account

```
solana create-stake-account \
  --fee-payer wallet-keypair.json \
  --stake-authority wallet-keypair.json \
  --withdraw-authority wallet-keypair.json \
  --from wallet-keypair.json \
  stake-account.json 0.5
```

Delegate Stake

```
solana delegate-stake \
  --fee-payer wallet-keypair.json \
  --stake-authority wallet-keypair.json \
  4EZRbSFYUQeuNCtY3Tv5tqprpTk9Ak7CZPzPsXKm1qLD 7R5of8HZreWPjURAMupJuik7vx5SAGUghpwU648bWYnt
```

[image]

How to put an additional stake in the public key `4EZRbSFYUQeuNCtY3Tv5tqprpTk9Ak7CZPzPsXKm1qLD`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit annoying, but you have to create and delegate a new stake account to the same validator, wait for the stake to activate, and then merge the new stake into the old stake.  For example:

- `solana create-stake-account --fee-payer wallet-keypair.json \ --stake-authority wallet-keypair.json \ --withdraw-authority wallet-keypair.json \ --from wallet-keypair.json \ new-stake-account.json 0.5`
- `solana delegate-stake solana delegate-stake \ --fee-payer wallet-keypair.json \ --stake-authority wallet-keypair.json \ new-stake-account.json 7R5of8HZreWPjURAMupJuik7vx5SAGUghpwU648bWYnt`
- wait for the stake to activate fully
- `solana --fee-payer wallet-keypair.json --stake-authority wallet-keypair.json merge-stake stake-account.json new-stake-account.json`